# SourceTree won't stop annoying me with password dialogs

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I keep getting this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

It repeats every few minutes, I close the popups every time. I don't want to enter any password and I don't want to be bothered any more.

I removed all repositories hosted on Bitbucket from SourceTree but it still happens. I tried to look in the View - Hosted repositories but it just keeps loading forever, I can't remove anything from there. Hosted account list is empty.

How to stop this annoyance?